# SSHClient() IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

```
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('devicenames',22,username=username,password=password)
```

I am getting "IndentationError: unexpected indent" in my python code.
I have written this code for SSH into Cisco devices but when I run this python code, it gives this error.

```
./device-config-backup.py
  ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('devicenames',22,username=username,password=password)`
  File "./device-config-backup.py", line 23
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Can someone let me know what could be the error ?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I got what was my mistake..

Comment: Now I am getting this error:                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./device-config-backup.py", line 29, in <module>
    ssh.connect('devicenames',22,username=username,password=password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 277, in connect
    socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known